# Facing "Devtools was disconnected from the page. Once page is reloaded, Devtools will automatically reconnect."

Tags: react-native, xcode9.3

I'm working on React-native js and Xcode 9.3 for iOS app development, but in between I get this error:

[image: Devtools error screenshot]

while debugging and becomes a road blocker for me to proceed in the debugging. Also referred few articles from here but didn't get anything for help.

I read [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35193296/chrome-48-devtools-was-disconnected-from-the-page-error?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) but it didn't work.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1):

I'm having a similar issue today.

Try reloading and snapshotting the page in incognito mode. For me, some of my extensions were interfering with the snapshots, and loading the page w/out them helped.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in my Angular App. I checked here [Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35193296/chrome-48-devtools-was-disconnected-from-the-page-error) but it didn't help me. For me the thing was that I had a huge select multiple  with a bunch of items. It was the reason that Chrome was throwing me that error since Chrome crash becouse of memory usage..
I read this article [Crashing browsers with Angular2 DebugElement](https://medium.com/@martatatiana/poor-detective-angular2-browser-crash-and-debugelement-f0a651dbf33) and it helped me with to found it out.

I hope this can help!

Comment: Hi @Lorena, Im facing same problem with angular application. Even im using huge select multiple with bunch of items. How did u solve it?

Comment: Hi @SVK, I reduced the amount of items lo load into the select multiple.

Answer (score 0):

Install https://www.google.com/chrome/canary/ and run Visual Studio, on the debug-Run [Play] button open dropdown cl'ck on Browse and select new installed google chrome canary browser (C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome SxS\Application\chrome.exe) as default debugger.

This worked for me.